# Angular query on mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Simply I am using **ng-model="query"** on my project as a search. It works great but for some reason it won't work on mobile (specifically iphone 5s). Is there any reason for this? I have tried searching for answers on google and haven't come up with anything.

Comment: Use 'data-ng-model="query"'

Comment: @A.J is it really `data` inside attribute does matter?

Comment: Html5 expects custom attributes to be prefixed with data. I am using cell phone so i can't post the link of blog explaining it now.

Comment: @A.J Glad to know that..add it as answer.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to HTML5 refer this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) link. It tells us what data attribute is and these are what Angular Js uses at the time of bootstraping.

So use `data-ng-model="query"`

Answer (score 2):

All I needed was **data-ng-model="query"**. Thank you user A.J